# Python Selenium select button

Tags: python, html, selenium, automation, pycharm

I am new to python and selenium (I have other programming knowledge). I try to program a script, which should upload content on instagram on given times (at least this is the goal). But I am stucking at the beginning. This is what I got so far:

```html
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

class InstagramBot:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def closeBrowser(self):
        self.driver.close()

    def acceptCookie(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
        time.sleep(2)
        acceptCookie_elem = driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="HoLwm")
        time.sleep(2)
        acceptCookie_elem.click()

    def login(self):
        driver = self.driver
        time.sleep(2)
        user_name_elem = driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="username")
        user_name_elem.clear()
        user_name_elem.send_keys(self.username)
        time.sleep(4)
        password_elem = driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="password")
        password_elem.clear()
        password_elem.send_keys(self.password)
        time.sleep(1)
        password_elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(2)

    def saveLogin(self):
        driver = self.driver
        saveLogin_elem = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//button[@class='yWX7d']")
        #saveLogin_elem = driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="yWX7d")
        time.sleep(2)
        saveLogin_elem.click()
```

Everything works except the saveLogin. I get following error:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //button[@class='yWX7d']

But html looks like this:

```html
<div class="cmbtv"><button class="sqdOP yWX7d    y3zKF     " type="button">Jetzt nicht</button></div>
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: try button[@class='sqdOP yWX7d']

Answer (score 0):

Try the xpath with below

```
//*[contains(text(),'Jetzt nicht')]
```

OR

```
//button[@class='sqdOP yWX7d y3zKF']
```

*Use expected_conditions to click*

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "myXpath")))

element.click();
```

***Import***

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. But still it doesn't work. I get following errors:


saveLogin_elem = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//button[@class='sqdOP yWX7d y3zKF']"):
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //button[@class='sqdOP yWX7d y3zKF']



saveLogin_elem = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//*[contains(text(),'Jetzt nicht')]"):
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //*[contains(text(),'Jetzt nicht')]

Comment: I tried following and it works:
    def saveLogin(self):
        driver = self.driver
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[normalize-space()='Jetzt nicht']"))).click()



...

However I also tried following: 
    def saveLogin(self):
        driver = self.driver
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/button[@class='yWX7d'"))).click()

But here I got error again. Could anyone explain me, why it is not working?